# Can wagtail set specific pages to be edited only by specific owner?

Tags: wagtail

I'm try to use PagePermissionHelper to set owner permission, but it's just let button disappear, user still can play it with url.

and hooks 'construct_main_menu' can play it with url too.

```
class ValidationPermissionHelper(PagePermissionHelper):
    def user_is_owner(self, user, obj):
        if user == obj.owner:
            return True
        else:
            return False

    def user_can_edit_obj(self, user, obj):
        return self.user_is_owner(user, obj)

class StorePage(ModelAdmin):
    model = Store
    permission_helper_class = ValidationPermissionHelper
```

Store is Page Model, so, PagePermissionHelper is the only choice?

how to really disable the edit permission?

Answer (score 0):

Pages are Per-Tree permitted, I think if you change settings of groups, giving them the per-instance permissions, would be better than the your code, unless you have (more complex use case)..!

[image]